# Bit confused on the concept of residuals

Tags: residuals

So I've just been introduced to the concept of residuals. I'm a bit confused. I understand that the fitted value is given by y^ = Z**beta^**; but I'm not sure I understand it. a^ and b^ are meant to be the values of the parameters that minimise the sum of squared differences. So how can it be applicable to multiple subscripts of i's? Surely those a^ and b^ values are only those values in one case? As I type this out I think I understand  more, it's an estimate not meant to be observed by values, but I'm not really sure between the distinguishment made by the residual between y_i and y^_i. Is it like, the differentiation between our model which is like a sort of line of best fit connecting the data, so the residual is like the difference between the observed value and the value we would expect from our model in our, kind of, line of best fit?

Comment: Could you edit your question and use $\TeX$ for formatting the math? To enable it, embrace the formulas with `$$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question you are interested in the difference between $\hat{y}_i$ and $y_i$. Essentially, the $\hat{\cdot}$ is telling you (as you surmised) something is an estimate. In the case of $\hat \beta$ this is the estimate of the parameter. Whereas $\beta$ is the true value. In the case of $\hat y_i$ this is a "predicted" value as a pose to the true value. The residual is the difference so $\hat\epsilon_i = y_i - \hat y_i$. In particular, these predicted values are:

$$\hat Y_i = X_i\hat\beta$$

To go to the actual observed data we then need to add in our error term (the residuals):

$$Y_i = X_i\hat\beta + \hat\epsilon_i$$

Comment: So could you potentially think of the residual as the distinguishment between the line of best fit created by Z*beta

Comment: Yeah take a look at the photo here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779773/python-linear-regression-best-fit-line-with-residuals